# Oracle JDBC driver: How to use /etc/ldap.ora and only specifying SID?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ldap

I have an Oracle connection using `com.oracle:ojdbc14:10.2.0.2.0` and the URL `jdbc:oracle:thin:@fooe2.company.intern:1529:odse` but would like to leave away the hostname and port as it may change over time. Using sqlplus I can just say "odse" and it will look the name up via /etc/ldap.ora. I know that there is a syntax where I can specify the ldap server names in the JDBC URL but I don't want that either as it may change as well.

Is it possible to have JDBC make use of the existing `/etc/ldap.ora` configuration and just specify the SID?

Comment: i think you'll need to use a THICK vs thin connection, then it can inherit the SQLNet/$ORACLE_HOME setup your sqlplus install is using, and you'll be able to take advantage of things like the existing ldap config.

Comment: Thick, i.e. driver type "oci" would probably work but it needs the shared library ocijdbc11.so or ocijdbc12.so, depending on the oci driver major version number in pom.xml. This means I need the same major version installed on all test/production servers. That's inconvinient, too. But thanks for the answer, I now understand the difference between thin and thick drivers.